# Ubuntu freeze on shutdown with AMD graphics card

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2

I installed dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS along with Windows 10 on a new DELL laptop (15 5000 series) with AMD Radeon R5 M335 graphics card.  Ubuntu will freeze on shutdown.   The GRUB boot menu has an option of booting from the Linux 3.19.0-49-generic recovery mode.    When I boot from this recovery mode and select “resume normal boot” in the follow-up menu, Ubuntu could be started and shut down without problem.

I tried various solutions suggested on the websites by adding reboot = bios in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line (e.g. http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.com/2011/11/solved-ubuntu-doesnt-shutdown-properly.html ).    They do not work for me.

I also tried to replace the default X.org driver for the AMD/ATI graphic with the fglrx driver.  This crushed the system and I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

I do not mind booting  from the recovery mode, but I would like to know the cause of my problem.  Could the X.org driver have issues with the AMD R5 M335 graphics card?

If you know a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

After I posted the question, I began to google on AMD Radeon graphic card.   I came across a webpage mentioning that the stable Linux Kernel 4.4 just released in January, 2016 has featured numerous AMD GPU additions on AMD graphics processors.    I followed the instructions given by http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-4-in-ubuntu/
to install Linux 4.4 in Ubuntu.    Ubuntu no longer freezes.   I can boot and shut down Ubuntu without problem.